# Langchain OpenAPIEndpointChain Memory Issue

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

I have been working on `Langchain` for the past few days. I'm structuring the data from user's input using API Specs. But I'm facing issues with the memory of the chain.

```
Technology: :Langchain
LLM Module: Vertex AI
Chain: OpenAPIEndPointChain, Method: from_api_operation
Operation: APIOperation, Method:from_openapi_spec
```

```
llm = VertexAI(max_output_tokens=1000, model_name="text-bison", top_k=0)
spec = OpenAPISpec.from_file(filepath)
operation = APIOperation.from_openapi_spec(spec, resource_path, method)
chain = OpenAPIEndpointChain.from_api_operation(operation, llm, requests=Requests(), return_intermediate_steps=True)
output = chain(question)
```

The chain provides me the parameters using spec docs only the current query, but I need the parameters based on the history of the queries.

Example:

```
Input: on 7th July
Current Output: {"date":"07/07/2023","time":""}
Input: at 4am
Current Output: {"date":"","time":"04:00"}
```

Expected Output:

```
{"date":"07/07/2023","time":"04:00"}
```

Thanks in advance!!